# CSS hover not working in a cloud navigation

Tags: html, css, hover

This is the first time I am working with CSS hover in this way. But it does not work.

I am trying to show a navigation cloud when the user hovers a item in the navigation.

This is my current CSS

```
.menuBox li a:hover,.menuBox li.selected a { color: #fff; background-color: #068dda; }

.menuBox .cloudnav { display: none; position: absolute; width: 995px; height: 500px; background-color: #fff; z-index: 999999; border: 1px solid #4a4d4b;}

.menuBox li a:hover>.cloudnav { display: block; }
```

This is my current html

```
<nav class="menuBox">
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="cloudnav">test</div>
</nav>
```

I even made a jsfiddle for you guys: http://jsfiddle.net/tAgEj/

I also tried `.menuBox li a:hover + .cloudnav { display: block; }` but that didn't work either.

What does?

Comment: [**Is this**](http://jsfiddle.net/tAgEj/1/) what you want? It's not a sibling of `li`, so you can apply it to the `ul` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work with the a:hover. But in newer browsers you can work it out like this

```
.menuBox ul:hover + .cloudnav { display: block; }
```

But this will only work in newer browsers, because many IE's don't support hover for something else than `<a>`

`.menuBox li a:hover>.cloudnav { display: block; }` this won't work because the `div.cloudnav` isn't a direct child of the `a` element. This would work if it would be

```
<a href="#">something<div class="cloudnav"></div></a>
```